# Его место рождения не/известно

Tags: орфография, частица-не, частица

Как пишется слово "не/известно" в предложении:
*Его место рождения "**не** известно" или "**не**известно"?*

Answer (score 2):

Правильно: **Его место рождения неизвестно.**

Это краткое прилагательное в функции именной части сказуемого, **основной формой является  слитное написание**.  Раздельно пишется при наличии усилительных слов: Его место рождения **никому не известно**.

Предикативное  наречие (в ф-ии сказуемого) **также чаще пишется слитно**:  Какая из двух сил перетянет ― **неизвестно**. **Неизвестно**, как обстоят дела сейчас.

Но при наличии усилительных слов: Но на данный момент мне **ничего** об этом **не известно**.

Answer (score 1):

Естественнее выглядит, конечно, слитное написание, но и раздельное не ошибка. Все зависит от того, хотите ли вы утверждать неизвестность или отрицать известность.

Общий принцип правописания НЕ с любыми частями речи: утверждается отрицательный признак – пишем слитно, отрицается положительный – раздельно. Ещё проще: есть отрицание – раздельно, нет – слитно.

Answer (score 0):

Оба написания возможны. Зависит от вкладываемого смысла.
Но обычной практикой в подобного рода написаниях является слитное, поскольку "неизвестно" воспринимается не как отрицание "известного", а как новое понятие, антоним исходного (ср. "безвестный").

Все попытки вывести императивное (строгое) правило из наличия зависимых или усилительных слов, осложненности предложения или типа дополнения (у нас - "место рождения") вряд ли правомерны, это всего ли статистические закономерности.